# Does the family of languages outputted by finite automata exactly form some type of languages in Chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

For a Turing machine, the language outputted by it is exactly a r.e. language. Any r.e. language can be the outputted language of some TM.

For a finite automaton with outputs (e.g. Mealy and Moore machines), does the language outputted by it belong to  some  type of languages in Chomsky hierarchy or its refinement? Does the family of languages outputted by finite automata with outputs exactly form some  type of languages in Chomsky hierarchy or its refinement?

[Is it correct that all the strings in language G(M) are generated by a TM M, as strings between a pair of #'s, when the input string to M is the empty string?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738084/do-the-languages-generated-by-a-tm-vary-for-different-input-strings) Similarly, how is the language generated/outputted by a Moore or Mealy machine  defined?

- What are considered as strings in the language?
- what is the input string to a  FA, when talking about the language outputted by the FA? Do the languages outputted by a FA vary for different input strings?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy): Type-3 grammars generate the regular languages. These languages are exactly all languages that can be decided by a finite state automaton.

Comment: See also Ian Chiswell, [A Course in Formal Languages Automata and Groups (Springer, 2009)](https://books.google.it/books?id=hjxdQLOrw3QC&pg=PA1), **Chapter 1 Grammars and Machine Recognition**

Comment: Could you quote specific sentences? My question is about the language generated/outputted by a FA with outputs, not accepted or recognized by a FA which might or might not output anything.

Comment: See the book... A *grammar* produces strings according to the rule. A "machine" (automata, Turing) make a computation with a string as input and stop after a finite amount of time (this is "recognize").

Comment: An automaton which outputs strings accept strings from a language and outputs strings in another language. For example, FAs without outputs vs Mealy and Moore machines.

Answer (score 2):

These are the regular languages, more often now called  rational languages.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the language generated by a finite automata a regular language?  Can any regular language be generated by a finite automata which outputs?

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77692/is-the-output-of-a-mealy-moore-automaton-a-regular-language

Comment: THanks. Is it true that  any regular language can be generated by a finite automata which outputs?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, every finite state machine can be viewed as a Mealy machine.

Comment: Thanks. I was also wondering https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734346/what-kind-of-functions-can-be-computed-by-finite-automata-with-outputs

Comment: Sorry that I just noticed my question needed to be clarified, so I did.  [Is it correct that all the strings in language G(M) are generated by M, when the input string to M is the empty string?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738084/do-the-languages-generated-by-a-tm-vary-for-different-input-strings) Similarly, what is the input string to a  FA, when talking about the language outputted by the FA? Do the languages outputted by a FA vary for different input strings? (Do you mind if I unaccept your reply and make my post open to accept more answers again?)

Comment: @Tim: Are you asking me?

Comment: Yes, I am......

Comment: You made a different question and unaccepted this answer. Both are very strange.

Comment: I upvoted your reply immediately when I saw it, as I always do for any reply. Don't be upset. It is my bad that my original questions needed more clarification: if no input string is specified, how can we talk about the generated language in our question and answer?

Comment: How is the language generated/outputted by a Moore or Mealy machine  defined?